# does it make sense to encrypt a password in javascript before submit?

Tags: javascript, sha512

I'm following the example on http://marakana.com/blog/examples/php-implementing-secure-login-with-php-javascript-and-sessions-without-ssl.html

The thing I don't fully understand is what is the gain by doing this? The secret word is posted in the form, so anyone who might be sniffing would surely see that secret word, as well as the javascript and be able to figure out the password anyways. Does it really make sense to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An eavesdropper would not be able to derive the password, because they only know:

- the secret word
- the *hash* of the secret word/password combination

Since hashes are one-way, you cannot derive the password itself from these.

**What you gain**: The user has set up a password which the server is able to verify, without having to send the plaintext password itself.

Comment: I will note that all this does is avoid sending the password in plain text. This provides no security against session hijacking (simply stealing the session cookie once the user is logged on).

Comment: @DarkFalcon: How is session hijacking related to the question?

Comment: Because the title of the linked article is "Implementing Secure Login with PHP, JavaScript, and Sessions"-which is not what the article describes how to do. It only specifies one small part: How to prevent sending the password as plaintext.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: It says secure "login" (only), so IMHO it works as advertised. But in any case, I think such comments would be better targeted at that article itself. The question asked here is much more specific: "why do this?"

Comment: I agree with @DarkFalcon here.  The point of securing the password is so that agents eavesdropping on the client/server exchange can't get access to your account.  But, if a session cookie is going to be generated after this login, then the eavesdropper can just grab the cookie and bypass the login entirely and still have access to your account.  You may have locked the front door, but the side and back doors are still wide open - not very secure.  It prevented stealing the pwd, but not access to the account.

Comment: @jfriend00: Well said, but there is an important difference: if the password is compromised then the attacker can use it to login on their own, at any time. Stealing your session would involve eavesdropping on the spot, and would not allow the attacker to keep using a stolen session forever.

Comment: @Jon - Yes, preventing stealing of the pwd is important for the reasons you mention.  But preventing the stealing of the session cookie is also required if you want any real protection from eavesdroppers.  Thus, this technique doesn't really provide meaningful security from eavesdroppers.  No meaningful security bar is met if the front door is locked, but all the other doors are wide open.  Yes, you've prevented an eavesdropper from getting a copy of your key, but you haven't locked the other doors so who cares.

Comment: quick question, if the  eavesdropper has the hash of the secret word/password combination, isn't that all he needs to log in later? I think I am missing a fundamental step...

Comment: @James: No, because the secret word is chosen by the server for each login attempt, and values already used would not be chosen again.

Comment: I think I am still missing something, and I don't think the web site I  mentioned in my original post is explaining it clearly enough for me. Could someone recommend a good tutorial or book that explains how this all works? Thanks!

Comment: I changed my search parameters and now am finding better search results. I think I should be all set now. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry for keeping this thread going. I think I have it figured out... but it only makes sense (to me) if I use a static secret word. On the DB store the hash of (salt+(pass+word)) and from the login screen send up the hash of (pass+word), I should be able to then  do (salt+(pass+word)) == (salt+(pass+word)).

Comment: @James: The db stores `hash(password)`. On auth, the server picks `secret` and sends it to client. User inputs `password`, client sends back `hash(secret + hash(password))`. Server knows `hash(password)` from db and it also knows `secret`, so it can calculate `hash(secret + hash(password))` independently. If the value matches the one supplied by the client, auth is successful.

Comment: @Jon, so that means on new user creation, we can't use a secret word?

Comment: Also, I thinking I need to store hash(salt+password) on the DB. How do I validate that against hash(secret + hash(password))? Does hash(secret+hash(salt+hash(password))) == hash(salt+hash(secret+hash(password))) ?

Comment: @James: Pick a salt randomly when the user is created and store `hash(salt + hash(password))` and `salt` in the database. When the user logs in also send `salt` to them in addition to `secret`. Replace `hash(password)` with `hash(salt + hash(password))` wherever it appears in my previous comment.

Comment: @Jon, So with regards to the eavesdropper in the middle, once the attacker gets that hashed string, he could send it up again thinking the server would authorize. But I suppose if I set the secret word in the $_SESSION for normal logon form, and assuming the secret word is random for every login, then the attacker's session would not have the correct word so authentication would fail.. But I can't send the user's salt because I don't know the user at the time of login

Comment: @jon when the login form is presented to the user, the server doesn't know who that user is yet, so I can't send the unique salt along with the login form.

Comment: You'd need a two-stage login to implement this strategy. In the first step, the only thing sent to the client is a form to enter the user's name. When that's submitted, the server replies with the salt for that user, and a form to enter the password. The actual submission and the rest of the process work as Jon outlined it. To avoid revealing whether the submitted user name is valid or not, the server should respond to step one by returning a secret-like value always, even if the user name isn't recognized.

Comment: Note that the second stage could be an ajax call run when the user name field changes, so it would appear to the user to be a single dialog.